# Proper syntax and use cases for MetaWhere in_all and in_any

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, meta-where

I've been exploring the capabilities of `MetaWhere` over the last couple of days. Most of the predications are pretty straightforward, but I'm stuck on how to use `in_all` and `in_any`.

Here are some of my attempts:

```
Group.where(:id.in_any => [1,2,3])
  => SELECT `groups`.* FROM `groups` WHERE ((`groups`.`id` IN (1) OR `groups`.`id` IN (2) OR `groups`.`id` IN (3)))

Group.where(:id.in_any => [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
  => undefined method 'visit_Fixnum' for #<MetaWhere::Visitors::Predicate:0x3740ba0>

Group.where(:id.in_any => [["1","2","3"],["4","5","6"],["7","8","9"]])
  => SELECT `groups`.* FROM `groups` WHERE (('1' AND '4' AND '7'))

Group.where(:id.in_any => ["(1,2,3)","(4,5,6)","(7,8,9)"])
  => SELECT `groups`.* FROM `groups` WHERE ((`groups`.`id` IN (0) OR `groups`.`id` IN (0) OR `groups`.`id` IN (0)))

Group.where(:id.in_any => ["1,2,3","4,5,6","7,8,9"])
  => SELECT `groups`.* FROM `groups` WHERE ((`groups`.`id` IN (1) OR `groups`.`id` IN (4) OR `groups`.`id` IN (7)))
```

I'm assuming they're supposed to `AND` or `OR` a bunch of `IN` clauses, but I can't figure out how to set them up properly, nor have I been able to find any decent documentation. And if anyone has any examples of situations where these predications would be useful, that would be appreciated as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes, it helps to go straight to the source. Looks like there's bug: https://twitter.com/#!/erniemiller/status/191151541342830592